# Selenium::WebDriver::Error with Firefox & Chrome

Tags: linux, selenium, rspec, parallel-processing, capybara

### Problems

#### 1. Browser = Firefox (Non Geckodriver, Selenium v2.53.4)

**(Works on one linux thin client but not on another...)**

`$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 120 seconds
```

#### 2. Broswer = Firefox (Geckodriver v0.14.0, Selenium-webdriver v3.1.0)

`$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`

```
 Net::ReadTimeout:
   Net::ReadTimeout
```

#### 3. Browser = Chrome (Chromedriver v2.27, Selenium-webdriver v3.1.0)

`$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
        no such session
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 ,platform=Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 x86_64)
```

### My Setup

1. Server with the following installed:
   -Linux - Debian x86_64 **Wheezy**
   -ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774)
   -Firefox v46.0.3
   -Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
   -ChromeDriver 2.27.440175
   -Xvfb (x11-xserver-utils v 7.7~3 through headless gem)

   #### Gems

   -Selenium v3.1.0 (was 2.53.4)
   **-parallel_tests v2.10.0**
   **-capybara (2.7.1)**
   -rspec-activemodel-mocks (1.0.3)
   -rspec-core (3.4.4)
   -rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
   -rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
   -rspec-rails (3.4.2)
   -rspec-support (3.4.1)
   **-headless (2.2.3) (Xvfb)**
2. Multiple thin clients running their software off the mentioned server setup.
   My computer is one of many...
   **Important: There is another computer that does NOT encounter the mentioned problem running the same software and same versions off the same server!**

### Things that are NOT the problem

1. It is not an incompatibility between my firefox browser version and Selenium.
   Why not?
   a) Firefox v46.0.3 and Selenium v2.53.4 is currently installed on our server and another client of this server successfully runs parallel_tests using the mentioned versions of Firefox & Selenium.
   b) [Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.53.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747430/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-2-53-0)
2. There are no zombie processes(still running firefox) causing firefox to lock port 7054.
   This is specifically after each failure has occurred and prior to starting a new `$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec` run.
   Why not?
   refer to items 1 & 2 in 'Things I Have Tried'
   **Turned Out this was not the case, although it was not the cause of the problem**
   Databases were not always properly killed, See Update 5.
   However the databases not being killed were an outcome of the problem.
   They were not the cause of the problem, refer to solution section.

### Side note

For those wishing to install the mentioned versions to get selenium / firefox working:
[Installing a previous version doesn't fix most problems](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Install-an-older-version-of-Firefox/ta-p/1564)

### Things I have tried

1. Removed any processes still running
   `$ killall ruby; killall rspec; killall firefox`
   **Result: Failed...**
2. Discovered that completing step 1 is not enough to kill all zombie processes.
   After logging out into a different tty i discovered that there was still an rspec, ruby and firefox process running!
   So I logged out of my user, logged into a new tty, killed all zombie processes using:
   `$ kill -9 process_id`
   I then rerun `$ ps aux` to ensure all processes are cleaned.
   **Result: Failed...**
3. Gain insight into the problem.
   Ran `$ lsof -i TCP:7054` see what is holding that process.
   **Result: It was my firefox test, no suprise, no real insight gained.**
4. Ensured parallel test databases were running correctly.
   Dropped all databases, recreated databases, reloaded all schemas, reseeded (development), reprepared.
   **Result: Failed... I doubted this was the cause, but doing this certainly eliminated it.**
5. Deleted firefox cache, all persisted setting, everything, for a clean start.
   **Result: Failed...**
6. Try to eliminate any local environment variables obtained from the project.
   Did this by copying the project directory from the working computer.
   Then reran `$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`.
   **Result: Failed...**
7. Try to eliminate all local environment variables (project and linux).
   Did this by creating a new linux user.
   Then switched into the new user.
   `$ su new_user -l`
   Copied over the minimum zsh items needed.
   Then ran `$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`
   **Result: Failed...**
8. [Ensured that /etc/hosts contained:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833411/ruby-unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-7054-within-45-seconds-seleniumwebdrive?rq=1).
   `127.0.0.1  localhost`
   **Result: Failed...**
9. Running the tests in a single thread (not parallel).
   `$ rspec spec`
   **Result: Successfully runs (does not hit the problem)**
10. See Update 1
11. See Update 2
12. See Update 3
13. See Update 4
14. See Update 5
    **Partial Solution**
15. See Update 6
    Debugged Selenium & Parallel_tests gems
    **Result: Identified that the issue is NOT in Selenium**
16. See Update 7
    **Result: Running tests in parallel worked. But why?**
17. See Update 8
    **Result:**
    Discovered Selenium 3.1.0 changed the way files are automatically downloaded.
    This caused tests to hang indefinitely whilst running parallel test.
    Which caused the databases to be held open.

### Things I am going to try (Updates)

1. Run tests with chromedriver in chrome browser and see if it passes after the fix.

### Update 1

I replaced firefox for chrome.
When I run a single test, the test successfully completes with chrome.
It did so with firefox as well.
However running `$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`
**Result: Failed...**

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
        no such session
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 ,platform=Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 x86_64)
```

### Update 2

I updated selenium-webdriver gem to the latest gem (was v2.53.4 now 3.2.2)
**Result: Failed...**

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
        no such session
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 ,platform=Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 x86_64)
```

### Update 3

Located lock file for parallel test (~.config/google-chrome).
Identified  3 persisting lock files.
Other users only had 1.
Deleted these and reran tests.
**Result: Failed...**

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
        no such session
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 ,platform=Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 x86_64)
```

### Update 4

Upgraded selenium-webdriver to v3.1.0 (latest stable)
Upgraded parallel_tests to v2.13.0 (latest)
Installed Geckodriver v0.14.0 (latest)
Then ran `$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`
**Result: Failed...**

```
Failure/Error: visit "#/login"

Net::ReadTimeout:
   Net::ReadTimeout
```

### Update 5

Whilst in the firefox (Geckodriver v0.14.0, Selenium-webdriver v3.1.0) branch.
I only realised when I had to drop all my parallel_test databases that some were still open.

```
@ltsp:~/ap$ bundle exec rake parallel:drop[32]
Couldn't drop ap_test_andre32 : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "ap_test_andre32" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 3 other sessions using the database.
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "ap_test_andre32">
Couldn't drop ap_test_andre25 : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "ap_test_andre25" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 3 other sessions using the database.
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "ap_test_andre25">
```

When rake parallel:spec does not complete (indefinetly hangs during ),
the process must be killed manually.
Doing so leaves databases locked to the parallel_tests that were using them at the time.
So they must be identified and cleaned up.

```
postgres   743  0.0  0.0 222364 33628 ?        Ss   15:30   0:00 postgres: andre ap_test_andre32 [local] idle in transaction                                                               
andre    24581  0.0  0.0   7852  2028 pts/36   S+   15:49   0:00 grep andre32
postgres 26822  0.0  0.0 220032 23400 ?        Ss   15:35   0:00 postgres: andre ap_test_andre32 [local] ALTER TABLE waiting                                                               
postgres 29684  0.0  0.0 220032 24064 ?        Ss   15:40   0:00 postgres: andre ap_test_andre32 [local] ALTER TABLE waiting
```

**Update 5 Solution:**
search for database processes & kill all of them
`ps aux | grep test_andre`
`andre@ltsp:~/ap$ sudo kill -9 743 26822 29684`
I was then able to drop my databases.
`bundle exec rake parallel:drop[32]`

### Update 6

Whilst in the firefox (Geckodriver v0.14.0, Selenium-webdriver v3.1.0) branch.
Cloned parallel_tests & Selenium projects locally.
Replaced my gems with a path to the locally cloned projects.
Debugged starting with the error stack trace.
**Results**
Updated to selenium 3.1.0 and loaded geckodriver (marionette).
I discovered that my firefox  profile was not setup correctly with Capybara.
This broke my local single thread tests.
Fixed this.
**Discovered that geckodriver is not to be used for FF<48.**
Also discovered that the capybara, selenium 3+ & FF48+ combo is not yet ready for use.
Some vital functions are not working. (Right clicking, window resizing...)
[Refer here for full details](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/1710)
After investigating parallel_tests, was able to rule that out.
Continued to debug in the firefox test case.
Used the locking port error as my guide.
Ruled out Selenium as the cause of the error.
After debugging the stack trace, it was proving to be very likely that the error state was inherited.
This was just a strong hunch at the time.
It later proved to be correct...
**So summary here was that firefox had processes that were being locked.

And they were not being locked by Selenium.**

### Update 7

Whilst in the firefox (Selenium-webdriver v2.53.4) branch.
Went back to the new linux user that was created.
In light of Update 5, I dropped cleaned up all running processes.
Dropped all databases.
`$ bundle exec rake parallel:spec`
**Result: Parallel tests worked**
But why?
The databases were not the cause of the issue.
There was something else.

### Update 8

Whilst in the firefox (Geckodriver v0.14.0, Selenium-webdriver v3.1.0) branch.
Identified the reason why the tests were failing and idenfinitely hanging.
This caused the issues described in Update 5 & 6.
It was caused by a change in the way Selenium accepts firefox profile settings.
I identified that the integration tests that were failing were ones that launched a pdf download.
Previously, I had this automated so that the download modal would not appear.
Instead it would automatically download the file to a specified folder.
Updating to Selenium 3.1.0 broke this.
Tests hanged indefinitely.
Databases were held open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems identified, in the updates were not the root cause.
**The root cause was** that firefox/chrome browser ports were not closed and held open.
After looking at htop, Polkitd was seen to be taking up 16.5gb of ram!
This was caused by **a memory leak in Polkitd**.
After checking the issues it was confirmed that Polkitd memory leak is a know issue.
The issue has been fixed but only in later distributions of linux debian and not for Wheezy.
After restarting Polkitd, and rerunning the tests in parallel they worked!
This explains why the first time I created a new linux user with a clean profile the parallel test issues were still occuring. - Memory leaks are unpredictable.
It also explains why another computer did not run into the issue.
And why the second time I created a new user the parallel tests worked!
Phew, that took a lot of effort!

Polkitd was uninstalled as it was not needed for any printers or other software that we run.

Overall, if anyone else has the locking issue, it would be helpful to follow some of the process detection that I have done as some of the issues are common to all OS.